# AJAX return API Data and use jQuery to Loop Through Nested JSON Data

Tags: jquery, arrays, json, ajax, for-loop

I'm using AJAX to connect to an API that is returning a JSON object (see JSON code reference below) and I'm attempting to loop through and parse the JSON data to render inside of an HTML element.

My code is outputting everything correctly EXCEPT it keeps returning the JSON data as `undefined`. I'm simply having issues actually grabbing the JSON data to inject it into the html elements I'm creating for each JSON `item` element.

```js
/* What the JSON object looks like being returned by the api */
/*
  "request": {
    "parameters": {
      "argument": {
        "@attributes": {
          "value": "service_name",
          "name": "sn"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "response": {
    "service": "group_search",
    "service_action": "execute",
    "availability": "public",
    "items": {
      "@attributes": {
        "count": "3"
      },
      "item": [{
          "id": "100",
          "name": "Item Nice Name",
          "meet_day_name": "Wednesday",
          "meet_time_name": "Noon",
          "description": "Item description",
          "area_name": {
            "@attributes": {
              "service_id": "0"
            }
          },
        },
        {
          "id": "101",
          "name": "Item Nice Name",
          "meet_day_name": "Monday",
          "meet_time_name": "Evening",
          "description": "Item description",
          "area_name": {
            "@attributes": {
              "service_id": "0"
            }
          },
        },
        {
          "id": "102",
          "name": "Item Nice Name",
          "meet_day_name": "Friday",
          "meet_time_name": "Morning",
          "description": "Item description",
          "area_name": {
            "@attributes": {
              "service_id": "0"
            }
          },
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
*/

if ($('body').data('groups') === 'search') {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'example.com/api.php',
    type: 'GET',
    success: function(data, textStatus) {
      console.log('Get status: ' + textStatus);
      console.log(data); // This is correctly dumping all json data to the console

      var groups_search = document.getElementById('groups');

      if (textStatus === 'success') {
        var output = '',
          remainder = '';

        for (var x = 0; x < data.length; x++) {

          /* This is being used to format HTML elements */              
          if (x % 3 === 0) {
            remainder = '0';
          } else if (x % 3 === 1) {
            remainder = '1';
          } else if (x % 3 === 2) {
            remainder = '2';
          }
          
          if (x % 3 === 0) {
            output += '<div class="row">';
          } // Wrap every row START

          /* This is where I need help correctly parsing the API data. 
           * Note the below JSON data is just referencing the data 
           * I'm trying to output and is not how I was actually 
           * trying to render it.
           */

          output += '<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-6 mb-col-' + remainder + '">';
          output += '<div class="group-item-inner">';
          output += '<h5 class="group-name">' + data.response.items.item.name + '</h5>';
          output += '<p class="meeting-time">' + data.response.items.item.meet_day_name + '|' + data.response.items.item.meet_time_name + '</p>'
          output += '<p class="service-id">' + data.response.items.item.area_name.attributes.service_id + '</p>'
          output += '</div>';
          output += '</div>';

          if (x % 3 === 2) {
            output += '</div>';
          } // Wrap every row END
        }

        groups_search.innerHTML = output;
      }

    }
  });
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>AJAX Group Search</title>

</head>

<body data-groups="search">
  <div id="groups">
    <!-- Inject the parsed and formatted JSON data here -->
  </div>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <!-- JS File using parsing API data -->
  <script src="scripts.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to process all items contained in the response, so change your loop:

```
for (var x = 0; x < data.response.items.item.length; x++) {
    ...
}
```

In your loop, you can then access each item by it's index:

```
data.response.items.item[x].name
```